# ERROR x509: certificate signed by unknown authority in Metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I try to pass **Metricbeats values to elasticsearch cluster**. while checking test output i faced this error.any one know how to fix this.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bUwr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me:

**metricbeat.yml**

```
   setup.kibana:   
     host: "hostname:5601"

   
   # ---------------------------- Elasticsearch Output ----------------------------
   output.elasticsearch:
     # Array of hosts to connect to:
     hosts: ["https://hostname:9200"]   
     protocol: "https"
  
     username: "elastic"
     password: "your-password"
   
     ssl.certificate_authorities: ["/path/to/elasticsearch/certs/certificate.pem"]
```

Adjust your `hostnames` and `ports` accordingly.

Hope this helped.